# Can't fetch data from an API on mobile phones

Tags: reactjs, api, react-hooks

I have made an application using Pokemon API in which I fetch Pokemon details from the API and show that in my app using React and hooks. It is working fine on the desktop. When I try it on different pixels using the inspect feature of chrome it works there as well, but when I try it on a mobile phone, it's not working - I can't get the Pokemon details from the API.

I have redeployed it many times and the same error persists. I have deployed the app on Vercel and here is the link - [https://react-pokedex-qjdjnph94-ateevduggal.vercel.app/.](https://react-pokedex-qjdjnph94-ateevduggal.vercel.app/)

I am not able to detect the problem. Can anyone help me?

Github link - https://github.com/Ateevduggal/React-Pokedex

Comment: It works for me on IOS. The first time I tried "Pikachu" and it gave an error, 404 not found. Then I typed "pikachu" lower case, and it worked.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Yes, it works with lowercase but I still don't why is this happening?

Comment: I would assume the pokemon api expects lowercase parameters. You must lowercase your user input string before sending it to the pokemon api.